# Querying active record based on the value of an associations attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `Post` model that `has_many :feedbacks, :through => another_model`. The `Feedback` model has a `:name` attribute.

I need the `Posts` that have `feedbacks` with more than 2 instances of a name.

For example:

> Post One has feedbacks with names of [Like, Like, Like, Spam]
>
> Post Two has feedbacks with names of [Dislike, Spam, Close].
>
> I want just Post One

The best I have gotten so far is...
`Posts.joins(:feedbacks).where`

I know I need to have a `group("name")` and a `having count > 2` but I cannot string together all of the clauses correctly.

**EDIT WITH CORRECT QUERY**

`Posts.joins(:another_models).group("posts.id", "another_models.feedback_id")
.having("COUNT(another_models.feedback_id) >= ?", 2)`

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
Post.joins(:feedbacks).group("posts.id").having("COUNT(feedbacks.id) > 2")
```

Comment: Thats close, however it is not also grouping on the feedbacks.name before counting. So in my example Post Two still gets pulled in because there are more than 2 feedbacks.ids in that array.

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
Post.joins(:feedbacks).group("posts.id").having("COUNT(DISTINCT(feedbacks.name)) < COUNT(feedbacks.id)")
```

Comment: I think this may work. I will come back and mark correct if so after some testing. Thanks.

Comment: This was not correct but an upvote for getting me close. Thanks.